# Is it possible to show a table row as soon as the data gets inserted with out inserting in codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, database, codeigniter, real-time

Is it possible to show a table row as soon as the data gets inserted with out inserting in codeigniter ? I don't want to use sockets but i also dont find a solution because when i use ajax the div replicates itself.

Comment: your question is not clear. also, could you add some code?

Comment: do you want the table row to be updated in the same same tab the user posted from? 
or a different tab/user table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using ajax.

We need 2 ajax call here.
1. For populating data.
2. For inserting data.

After successful insertion of data you can initiate the List function.
An example of the code is given below.

```
function populateList(){

   var resultHtml = '';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'api/for/getting/list/of/data',
        data:{},
        cache: false,

    success:function(response) {


        $.each(response.list,function(key,val){
            resultHtml += '<tr>';
            resultHtml += val.name;
            resultHtml += '</tr>';
            resultHtml += '<tr>';
            resultHtml += val.mobile;
            resultHtml += '</tr>';
            resultHtml += '<tr>';
            resultHtml += val.address;
            resultHtml += '</tr>';
        })

        //Populate in in the <tbody> of the table
        $('#list_table').html(resultHtml);

    }
  });
}




 $('#insert_buttom').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'api/for/inserting/data',
        data:{},// pass all the data here
        cache: false,

    success:function(response) {
       populateList();
    }
  });
 })
```